# Quadratic Programming Convex Optimisation notation

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am trying to understand how to solve convex optimisation problems using solvers such as CVXOPT as I am trying to solve a convex problem and would need to know how to plug in these numbers into the solver. My knowledge of this field is thus very limited.

Most of the quadratic programming problems that is phrased is in the formform *minimize* $1/2x^TPx + q^Tx  $ subject to $Gx \preccurlyeq h, Ax = b$.

However, the problem that I face is when there are more than 2 variables to minimise / maximise. An example is shown here
$w^T$, and $\mu$ are vectors and $t$ is a scalar.

[image]

This image is taken from the https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icml04-apprentice.pdf I am not sure how 2 variables can be minimised / maximised at the same time.

Comment: The above problem can be solved via the dual, it is the nearest point in the convex hull of the $\mu^{(j)}$ to $\mu_E$.

Comment: Would u be able to link me a tutorial/readings that talks about that method ? Thank you :-)

Comment: I don't have any specific reference, unfortunately. Two comments: (1) Perhaps you could watch the video https://youtu.be/N2b_B4TNfUM, that would gives an idea how the above problem would be solved in CVX. (2) The above is equivalent to solving $\max_{t,\|w\| \le 1} \min_j w^T(\mu_E-\mu^{(j)})$ and the dual results in a nearest point computation.